# Compiler Error cs8032

Tags: c#

Hello I made a csharp script and it keeps given me this compiler error(error cs8032:Internal compiler error during parsing.Run with-v for more details).Here is the script.

```
using UnityEngine;  
using System.Collections;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class MoveObject : MonoBehaviour {


    public float speed;
    private float amoutToMove;
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM3",9600);

    void Start () {

        sp.Open();
        sp.ReadTimeout = 1;
    }

    void Update () {
        amoutToMove = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        if (sp.IsOpen) {
            try
            {
                MoveObject(sp.ReadByte());
                print(sp.ReadByte());
            }
            catch(System.Exception)
            {
            }

        }
    }
}

void MoveObject(int Direction)
{
    if (Direction == 2)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.left * amoutToMove, Space.World);
    }

    if (Direction == 1)
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.right * amoutToMove, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time, please be more careful about formatting. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: The compiler should also give you the line number where this error happens. Can you add this info to your question?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to create class and method with the same name.
Try to rename your method.

One more thing, you are using amoutToMove variable in your method, but it's declared in your class and it's not in your method's scope. It's another error. But currently compiler can't give you that error due to the same names in class and method.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you need to rewrite it like this

```
private SerialPort sp;

void Start () {
    sp = new SerialPort("COM3",9600);
    sp.Open();
    sp.ReadTimeout = 1;
}
```